# How to convert repeating columns to single rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with description like bellow

```
Title1 Value1 Title2 Value2 Title3 Value3
------------------------------------------
haha   123    hohoho  321    kikiki  1223

ab     212    iii     233    kjkj    7474
```

and I want to query like bellow

```
Title   Value
--------------
haha    123

hohoho  321

kikiki  1223

ab      212

iii     233

kjkj    7474
```

and there cloud be duplicate values.
If there are 3 dups, Results contains 3 dups.

Are there any good ways to query ??

Comment: er, your question reads a bit ambiguously to me; do you want to _get rid_ of the duplicates, or _keep_ them?  Why?  Generally speaking, you shouldn't need duplicate rows (given the way SQL works) - this is especially true if you're pivoting the table to a new form permanently...

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT Title1 Title, Value1 Value FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT Title2, Value2 FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT Title3, Value3 FROM table
```

Comment: +1 as an side note @walkingFox keep in mind that UNION or UNIONS ALL is always using an internal temporary (HEAP or MyISAM disk based) table ->  see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54178/how-to-get-rid-of-using-temporary-when-using-distinct-in-mysql/54184#54184 so watch out how much data you select with this construct

Comment: Absolutely. The best approach would be not to even store data this way in the first place :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT Title1 Title, Value1 Value FROM <tablename>
UNION ALL (SELECT Title2, Value2 FROM <tablename>)
UNION ALL (SELECT Title3, Value3 FROM <tablename>)
```

Comment: in future dont copy cat the answer .. your answer is same as the above one

Comment: i am not copied , but yes the answer is same ,